# Can't edit my np.fromstring

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, wav, pyaudio

I created a sound this way :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write   
data=np.random.uniform(-1,-1,44100)
scaled=np.int8(data/np.max(np.abs(data))*127)
write('test8.wav',44100,scaled)
```

and I want to convert amplitudes using np.fromstring :

```
def tableau_ampli(filename) :
    Monson = wave.open(filename,'r')
    n = Monson.getnframes()   
    if Monson.getsampwidth() == 1 : 
        freq = np.fromstring(Monson.readframes(n),dtype=np.uint8)
        print(freq)
        for k in range(n):
            if freq[k] > int(127) :
                freq[k]=freq[k]-249
        print(freq)
    else : 
       freq = np.fromstring(Monson.readframes(n),dtype=np.uint16)
       for k in range(len(freq)):
           if freq[k]>32767 :   # 32767 = [(2**16)/2]-1
                freq[k]-=65536    # 65536 = 2**16
    return(freq)
```

but it doesn't work when I execute tableau_ampli('test8.wav').
I think the problem is because

```
 np.fromstring(Monson.readframes(n),dtype=np.uint8)
```

returns : `[129 129 129 ..., 129 129 129]` and not an array or a string.
Can I get some help ?

Comment: `[129 129 129 ..., 129 129 129]` is an array of `uint8`, just as you specified.

Comment: but why can't I edit it ? when I execute 
    for k in range(n):
            if freq[k] > int(127) :
                freq[k]=freq[k]-249
        print(freq)

However when I execute it on  : array([129,129,129,129,129,129])  it does work :/

Comment: What is `wave` in the first line in `tableau_ampli()`? When I try running this snippet, it gives me an error there.

Comment: can you be more specific about what is not working? Do you get an error? Or an undesired result? What do you expect instead?

Comment: It returns : array([136, 136, 136, ..., 136, 136, 136], dtype=uint8)  however, it is supposed to return : array([-120, -120, -120, ..., -120, -120, -120], dtype=uint8)

Comment: you should first : import wave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the elements in `freq` are of `uint8`, which gives us an unsigned integer from (0 to 255). See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).
So when you subtract something from it, let's say `x`, it forces it into the range 0 to 255 by performing 256 - `x`. Since 256 - 249 = 136, this is what you get.

You can change `freq = np.fromstring(Monson.readframes(n),dtype=np.uint8)` to `freq = np.fromstring(Monson.readframes(n),dtype=np.uint8).astype(int)` to convert it to an int data type and get -120.